# Wald: 2-dim Covariant Derivative for Null Hypersurfaces

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, differentiation

On pp. 221-222, Wald introduces the 2-dim "hatted" manifold of null geodesics.  He moves from 9.2.30 to 9.2.31 and he is allowed to do so because the tensors have the special properties that he describes at the top of the page.  I have several questions about this, but the main one is: how do we go from the 4 dimensional covariant derivative to the 2 dimensional covariant derivative?  The derivative in 9.2.31 is unhatted and it is unclear why that is so.  I'm not even sure how the hatted one is supposed to be defined.  I wrote down the most natural definition but I couldn't even show that it was well defined.  Understanding exactly how the special properties work is not obvious in the case of tensors.  Is the contraction within a tensor, for example?  But he does not even address how derivatives behave when hatted.  (I'm sorry for not writing the equations, but I couldn't get the hats to format properly.)

Comment: There is no hatted derivative. All derivations are withing the 4d manifold.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  So do you then think that in eq. 9.2.31 that Wald is mixing 2dim indices with 4dim ones??  The hatted B's have 2dim indices I think you would agree.  But then the covariant derivative in the k direction does not have 2dim indices?  I am not sure you are wrong and had considered that to be a possibility.  Can you elaborate?